# Can create extension but can't alter in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-extensions

The extension was created by user `deploy` with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

now I need to move extension to another schema (still as a `deploy` user, schema `utils` is owned by `deploy` user too). So I do:

```
ALTER EXTENSION ltree SET SCHEMA utils;
```

which fails with:

ERROR:  must be owner of extension ltree

So 2 questions:

1. Why does PG allow creating the extension for `deploy` user but not altering it by the same user?
2. How can I change the schema of the extension still being the `deploy` user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The extension has to be relocatable to move to another schema.

The easiest solution is probably to just drop the extension from your schema, then create it in a new schema.

Comment: Relocatable? Is that a permission or what? Why the extension created by the same user can't be reallocated to the schema created by the same user? Dropping extension isn't a good option because there are too many dependent objects (which I'll have to drop and recreate too).

Comment: I just checked ltree.control and it has relocatable = true, on 9.3. What is your version? Can you check ltree.control and see what the setting for relocatable is?

Comment: What kind of dependent objects do you have? These may also interfere with the schema change.

Comment: I'm on PG 9.3. Dependent objects are functions that refer to `ltree`, `lquery` (without fully qualified path) and few columns. So I just add `utils` schema to the DB's `search_path`.